# Ubuntu with Desktop that's under 700 MB and works with Dell optiplex 755 usff

Tags: dell

I have a dell optiplex 755 usff that I have setup to use with a new os. I don't have any dvd's currently at the moment so i'm stuck with cd's for right now which can hold 700 MB and I want it to be compatible with my dell optiplex 755 usff, for being able to do anything that a windows os can do. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: You can start with a [mini ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), which is only about 50MB, and installs a command line base system. Once that is installed, you can then install any DE you like.

Comment: Or use a USB stick instead, much faster and reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a [mini ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), which is only about 50MB, and installs a command line base system. Once that is installed, you can then install any DE you like.

None of the other Ubuntu images I've seen will fit on a 700MB CD.